# Is it possible to change the icon and the application name in the google developer console?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have created an apk with kivy/buildozer, can I change the icon and the application name in the google Developer Console?

Comment: I don't think so, you should set these when building the APK.

Comment: how can I change the default kivy icon with buildozer spec? I have tried various methods but they have not worked

Comment: How can we help you if we don't know what you have already tried?

Comment: in the virtual machine buildozer in the home i have this 3 files 1) main.py 2)photo.png (the icon 512x512 ) and the 3)photo.jpg and the 4) buildozer.spec is in the places kivy. i open the terminal i write buildozer init i adjust the buildozer spec and i write buildozer android_new debug i create the file apk i transfer in my smartphone and app not work.
if i not modify the icon.filename in buildozer spec the app in my smartphone work good and show my photo.jpg.Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in changing the main kivy icon

Comment: who help me im a beginner not a pro thanks